# why is my return statement unreachable after try-finally?

Tags: c#, unreachable-code

Here is my code.  I have a method that deletes an Azure Block Blob.  I have a try / finally block to log the failure with details, but otherwise to carry on.

I am returning a `bool` to identify if the item was deleted or not.

Visual Studio is telling me that the `return` statement at the end of the method is unreachable.

```
public bool Delete(string referenceId)
{
    var client = GetBlobClient();
    var container = client.GetContainerReference("qwerty");
    var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(referenceId);
    try
    {
        blob.Delete();
        return true;
    }
    finally
    {
        Trace.TraceWarning("Delete Blob failed: {0}", referenceId);
    }
    return false;  // <-- THIS LINE.
}
```

[image]

Why is that? Don't I have to return some value in this method.

Your insight is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry man.  I'm just trying to understand the language better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have no catch, so if there's an exception in your try it will just be thrown. Your method either succeeds and returns true, or an exception is thrown.

If you add a catch block, the warning will go away because that path is now accessible.

You should be able to swallow the exception (if that's what you want) by simply adding `catch {}` before the finally.

Looking at your code more closely, you likely want to replace the `finally` with a `catch` anyways- it's unlikely you wish to log that the delete had failed no matter the outcome.

Comment: I originally removed the `catch` to try to identify what sort of exception I'd get if the delete failed ... and I never replaced it. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 2):

The code is unreachable because of the `return` statement that you have in your `try` block, which will always execute unless an `exception` is thrown.

If the `Delete()` method of the `blob` variable executes seamlessly then the `return` statement in the `try` block will be executed and the method will exit (after the `finally` block has run) without executing any further instruction after the `try`/`finally` block. Otherwise, if it throws an `exception`, then the `exception` itself will propagate to the caller method (again, after the `finally` block has run) and neither `return` statement will be executed. In either case, the `return` statement at the end of the method will never be reached.

If you however delete the `return` statement inside the try block, you will verify that the code still successfully compiles and the `return` statement at the end of the method is reachable.

Cheers.